# How to Prevent iOS app from hook theOS or others

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, theos

I've been searching for 2 days to prevent my app from jailbreak device, and I got it, the problem is I still can hook my class use theOS and override the jailbreak check function.

Do you have any proven Idea maybe , framework , library or something else ?

Comment: We have been using [Arxan](https://www.arxan.com/products/application-protection/mobile/ensureit-for-apple-ios/) from EnsureIT.

Comment: thanks for the answer Vin ... I saw the price is really expensive :D ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dyld](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/index.html) for that.

`_dyld_image_count` returns a number of dynamic libraries loaded into your application address space. Then you can iterate over them using `_dyld_get_image_name` checking dynamic library path. That way you can determine whether CydiaSubstrate library or any dynamic library with unknown path been loaded into your application.

Of course with jailbreak even those functions can be hooked and I don't think you can do much about it. Arxan claims it can do something with it but even if it detects something you can always hook any function it uses for detection. CydiaSubstrate tweaks are always one step ahead because they're loaded before `main` is called. Thus it can hook everything it wants in constructor and you can't do anything about it.

Without jailbreak only way to load malicious library is to modify and resign your app so that it links against the library. Without jailbreak you can't hook C functions so `_dyld_get_image_name` will be able to detect that library.

Comment: thanks for your comment dude ... I realize without any security IT solution support , it's almost impossible to avoid hook , currently i just made method for checking jailbreak and cracked app in fancy name :D ...